# Continuous build and run with SBT

Tags: sbt

I'm tyring to find a better method to run my SBT project with continuous build (compile) and run, SBT can already do continuous compile and test but not with the `run` command unless I'm not aware how that is possible.

I tried using the `~` command on `run` but it does nothing
`sbt clean compile ~run`

I tried using the spray sbt plugin
`addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1")`
but it is so tempremental and hangs a lot while trying to kill the current process making it faster to just kill the app then run `sbt clean compile run`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it does nothing? `sbt clean ~run` works fine for me (`compile` there is redundant). You change sources, it reruns the program. Which behaviour do you expect?

Comment: I expect if I edit scala files that it would recompile and restart the app, I have a jetty server with some basic stuff runing like twirl templating

Comment: The problem is that your main doesn't return. sbt won't kill it to rerun. So I think that using sbt-revolver is your best choice. If you have some particular problem with it, you can add details to the question (or ask a new one). Last time I used it, it worked really well, so probably it's something about your setup.

Comment: hmmm... interesting speculation, my main class has a jetty server start and right at the end I have a call to a separate method to handle shudowns `sys.addShutdownHook` that stops the jetty server, do you think I should return something specific?

Comment: No, I mean that your main method doesn't terminate (because a server is not supposed to). So while it's running, sbt won't interrupt it. But sbt-revolver does, I think.

Comment: aaa ok makes sense, to bad this is the case, play framework manages to resolve that somehow, maye checking their sourcecode on github will give me an idea, thanks for a quick reply @laughedelic

Comment: OK. So I'm going to post it as an answer then. And about Play: it uses it's own file watching mechanism independent of sbt's `~`.

Comment: that makes sense as I didn't see any out of the box plugins being loaded in their library imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sbt clean ~run` should work fine and rerun main method every time you change the sources. But if you're running a web server which is supposed to run continuously, sbt won't interrupt it to rerun.

So you should use sbt-revolver for that and solve any problems with it by either asking another question or submitting a bug report for the plugin.